How do I put a text divider in a Recyclerview with a StaggeredGridLayoutManager?
I'm trying to put some text dividers containing a timestamp inbetween the items of a RecyclerView with a StaggeredGridLayoutManager.
I tried using the ItemDecoration class but I think it can't do text and also it doesn't really work for a staggered grid.
My Item Decoration class:
class TImestampItemDecoration(context: Context, space: Int = 30) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
private val spaceInDp = dpToPx(context, space)

override fun getItemOffsets(
    outRect: Rect,
    view: View,
    parent: RecyclerView,
    state: RecyclerView.State
) {
    outRect.bottom = spaceInDp
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
        outRect.top = spaceInDp
    }
}

fun dpToPx(context: Context, dp: Int): Int {
    return (dp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
}

}
adding the item decoration to the recyclerview:
 binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(TImestampItemDecoration(requireContext()))

I solved it myself. I created a different Item view with just a text view and submitted it to the viewHolder via submitList(). I then did this to make it occupy the whole width of the recyclerview:
        val layoutParams: StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams? =
            viewHolder.itemView.layoutParams as StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams?
        layoutParams!!.isFullSpan = true

